Is Possible Mongodb Transaction progress without Replica Set?
I'm working on a small project and I've chosen MongoDB as the database. However, I'm experiencing some regrets. I've learned that a replica set is required for transaction operations. I'm working on a VPS and I don't want to create a Docker just for transactions. My Node.js application is using MongoDB version 7.0. Is there a way to use transactions in a Cluster > Standalone setup?

A replica set can be comprised of as few as 1 mongod process. So the answer to your question as you've asked it is both no and yes. Remember that a single node replica set does not provide any high availability features and has greater risk of data loss as that sole mongod process represents a single point if failure

Thanks for the advice.  I made a configuration with run-rs and pm2.  I don't know how much I can trust yet.
